# Javascript function not found, but is referenced in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple web page. On the page load, I need to make an ajax request and retrieve some data. I am then trying to create a ReportCardData 'object' with this data as a parameter. When trying to run this code, I am getting an error that `ReportCardData` is not defined?

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<script src="js/reportCard/ReportCardData.js>"></script>
<script src="js/reportCard/ReportCardGrabber.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="ReportCardGrabber();">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**ReportCardGrabber.js**

```
function ReportCardGrabber(){
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url: 'http://xx.xx.xxx.x/getReportCard.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success : function (result){
        if(result['returnCode'] == 1){
            var data = $.parseJSON(result['returnMessage']);
            var reportCardData = new ReportCardData(data);
        }else{
            //error
        }
    }

});
```

}

**ReportCardData.js**

```
function ReportCardData(rawData)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
src="js/reportCard/ReportCardData.js>"
                                    ^
```

Your filename is wrong.

Comment: @nicael well this could as well be a comment instead of an answer, and this question is supposed to be closed anyway, since this is a simple typographical error.

Comment: @nicael — Because the question should be closed because it is due to a typo so I don't want to get points from it or appear to be rep harvesting, but having an answer that addresses the problem will discourage other people from copying a comment as an answer.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for spotting it. It's a shame my IDE didn't say anything